Maui ToolbarItem tint color in Android
Is it possible to change ToolbarItem icon tint color on Android? I don't want to implement my own Shell.TitleView (for various reasons), just to change icon colour?
This is what I get in Android:

And this is how it looks in iOS:

And this is XAML for Toolbar:
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem 
        x:Name="SignReport"
        IconImageSource="signup24.png"
        Command="{Binding SignReportCommand}"/>
    
    <ToolbarItem 
        IconImageSource="sendemail24.png"
        Command="{Binding EmailReportCommand}">
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

Notice that in iOS it's automatically set to correct colour, e.g. white, but Android is black.

The easiest way I thought is to edit the Project file. For the image, you could set,
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <!-- Images -->
    ...
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\myImage.png" Resize="True" tintColor="#FFFFFF" />

     ...
</ItemGroup>

Then the tint color should be white.
